# set values of 2D numpy array by parameters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to create 2D np array by the known shape and parameters in this way:

```
import numpy as np
rows = 9
cols = 8
xrows = 3
xcols = 2
```

the wanted results:

```
([[ 1,  1,  4,  4,  7,  7, 10, 10],
    [ 1,  1,  4,  4,  7,  7, 10, 10],
    [ 1,  1,  4,  4,  7,  7, 10, 10],
    [ 2,  2,  5,  5,  8,  8, 11, 11],
    [ 2,  2,  5,  5,  8,  8, 11, 11],
    [ 2,  2,  5,  5,  8,  8, 11, 11],
    [ 3,  3,  6,  6,  9,  9, 12, 12],
    [ 3,  3,  6,  6,  9,  9, 12, 12],
    [ 3,  3,  6,  6,  9,  9, 12, 12]])
rows%xrows = 0
cols%xcols = 0
```

rows is the number of rows of the array, cols is the number of columns of the array, xrows is the number of rows in each slice, xcols is the number of column in each slice.
the answer should be general not for this parameters

Comment: could you be more specific on what each parameter is defining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
((np.arange(rows//xrows*cols//xcols, dtype=int)+1)
 .reshape((rows//xrows,cols//xcols), order='F')
 .repeat(xrows,0)
 .repeat(xcols,1)
 )
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  1,  4,  4,  7,  7, 10, 10],
       [ 1,  1,  4,  4,  7,  7, 10, 10],
       [ 1,  1,  4,  4,  7,  7, 10, 10],
       [ 2,  2,  5,  5,  8,  8, 11, 11],
       [ 2,  2,  5,  5,  8,  8, 11, 11],
       [ 2,  2,  5,  5,  8,  8, 11, 11],
       [ 3,  3,  6,  6,  9,  9, 12, 12],
       [ 3,  3,  6,  6,  9,  9, 12, 12],
       [ 3,  3,  6,  6,  9,  9, 12, 12]])
```

Comment: I can use that, but better if it possible to tune the slices by column not by rows

Comment: @user18628648 sure, that was an oversight, see update